# There is a greyscale in my alpha mask I extracted from a .mov file, is there any way to make the alpha mask .mov only white and black?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, quicktime, mask

so what the title says. I've never used ffmpeg before but I really need to extract an alpha mask for a project. The problem is a grey color which should be white so when I merge it with the main video there is transparency where there shouldn't be.

I used the command

```
ffmpeg -i angry.mov -filter:v alphaextract mask.mov
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i angry.mov -vf alphaextract,format=yuv420p 123.mov
```

is there any other way to do it? I did the original mov file from png images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use [lutyuv filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-lut_002c-lutrgb_002c-lutyuv), but it may be too complicated if your never used FFmpeg before.

Example for converting all gray values in the alpha channel to white:

`ffmpeg -i angry.mov -vf alphaextract,lutyuv="y=(val-(maxval-1))*maxval" -pix_fmt gray 123.mov`

---

Example:
Input image: `peppers_alpha.png`:
[image]
As you can see there are semi-transparent pixels.
(You may download the above image for executing the code samples below).

---

Extracting alpha channel using `alphaextract` filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i peppers_alpha.png -vf alphaextract -pix_fmt gray alpha.png`

Result:
[image]
As you can see the semi-transparent pixels turned to gray levels (and the opaque pixels are zeros).

---

Turning the semi-transparent pixels to black pixels using `alphaextract` and `lutyuv` filters:

`ffmpeg -y -i peppers_alpha.png -vf alphaextract,lutyuv="y=(val-(maxval-1))*maxval" -pix_fmt gray new_alpha.png`

Result:
[image]
As you can see, the semi-transparent pixels turned to black.

Note: `maxval` = `255` for 8 bits images.

---

We may adjust adjust the threshold by subtracting `50` instead of `1` (for example):

`ffmpeg -y -i peppers_alpha.png -vf alphaextract,lutyuv="y=(val-(255-50))*255" -pix_fmt gray new_alpha.png`

Result:
[image]

---

Why `y=(val-254)*255` sets pixels in range [0, 254] to 0?

Explanation:
All the mathematical operations are applied with clipping to [0, 255].
Values below `0` are clipped to `0` and values above `255` are clipped to `255`.

`val-254` is `0` (after clipping) for all values except `255` (for values in range [0, 254]).

So for val in [0, 254] the result is:

`0*255` = `0`

And for val = 255 the result is:

`(255-254)*255` = `255`

Comment: Just created an account to thank you, I did use (255-254)*255 and now it looks as it should. Thanks again